# How to create this desktop recorder?

Tags: c++, c, windows, image-processing, desktop

I want to create a desktop recorder that require very little HD space.

It should capture the current display into a buffer, compare it to the previous state, and save only the rectangles that differ to the previous state.

What API, function or library I have to use ?

Comment: Are you writing a keylogger/trojan? Your previous questions ring a bell to me.

Comment: I am writing a program like camstudio.

Comment: do you also **send** it over the network, **hide** its initialisation and **monitor** what other applications are doing? I flagged for moderation attention. Sorry.

Comment: Indeed, there does seem to be a certain... "trend" that is attracting lots of negativity from multiple users. The SO crowd is a very straight laced community; I'm not sure this is necessarily the right place to try to piece together an invisible screen-transmitting, system monitoring, auto-running ghost application.

Comment: @Marc And then what to do? Should this be treated on Meta? Downvoting doesn't seem the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to save the differences from each frame to frame only you could simply use a substraction-method. Simply substract the color values at image(t+1) from image(t)... All parts that stay equal haven't changed... only the parts that are different will result in something non-zero. You can then extract the rectangles around it and save them. But of course be aware since there might be more than one part changing of course and you probably wanna save each one instead of the big rectangle that contains all changes...

You could use OpenCV for this... it has all basic functions for image substraction, rectangle fitting, cropping, ...

Hope that helps...

Comment: why not? a black pixel has a grayscale value of 0 (if we just assume one channel now, would work as well for RGB). Substracting 0 from another grayscale value 'x' would leave x and would not result in zero. Only pixels with the same grayscale value in the two images will result in 0 wenn substracting one from another. Only disadvantage would be some kind of ghosting effect, if some kind of homogeneous area is moving over the screen. The method will only detect the outer parts. But there are ways of eliminating this effect by i.e. having a look at three following images.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Windows Media Screen Capture encoder for the task.  You will feed your captured frames to it, and it will do the rest and create highly efficient wmv file for you.